# Show/Hide google line chart using listbox in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, listbox

I drawed a line chart using google API. However, I want to do show/hide multi line chart function using listbox in JavaScript. The chart will only show the line which are selected. Here is my code but it's not working. Can help me check? Thank a lot.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
    function init(){
        var rowData1 = [['Year', 'Sales']
                        ['2003',  100.00],
                        ['2004',  90.29],
                        ['2005',  241.03],
                        ['2006',  134.61],
                        ['2007',  151.06],
                        ['2008',  133.96],
                        ['2009',  103.20,],
                        ['2010',  110.00],
                        ['2011',  115.53],
                        ['2012',  242.44],];

        var rowData2 = [['Year', 'Marketing'],
                        ['2003',  100.00],
                        ['2004',  94.22],
                        ['2005',  81.85],
                        ['2006',  108.01],
                        ['2007',  88.44],
                        ['2008',  88.07],
                        ['2009',  108.40],
                        ['2010',  149.01],
                        ['2011',  156.29],
                        ['2012',  130.15],];

        var rowData3 = [['Year', 'Expenses'],
                        ['2003',  100.00],
                        ['2004',  194.22],
                        ['2005',  41.85],
                        ['2006',  128.01],
                        ['2007',  98.44],
                        ['2008',  128.07],
                        ['2009',  148.40],
                        ['2010',  139.01],
                        ['2011',  196.29],
                        ['2012',  230.15],];


        //var data = [];
        //data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData1);
        //data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData2);
        //data[2] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData3);

        var options = {
          width: 700,
          height: 400,
          vAxis: {title: "Amount"},
          hAxis: {title: "Year"},
          animation:{
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
          },
        };
    }

    function drawMultiChart(){
        var listBox=document.getElementById("selectMultiple");
        var count=0;
        var itemToDraw=Array();
            itemToDraw(0) = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData1);
            itemToDraw(1) = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData2);
            itemToDraw(2) = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData3);

        for (var i=0;i<listBox.options.length;i++){
            if (listBox.options[i].selected==true){
                itemToDraw.push(listBox.options[i].value);
            }
        }

        for (var j=0;j<itemToDraw.length;j++){
            count+=drawOneByOne(listBox,itemToDraw[j]);
        }
    }

    function drawOneByOne(listBox,itamToDraw){
        var drawed=0;
        for(var k=0;k<listBox.options.length;k++){
            if(listBox.options[k].value==itemToDraw){
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
                view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                chart.draw(data, options);
                drawed =1;
                break;  
            }
        }
        return drawed;              
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>  
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <table border="0"> 
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Select One Industry</td>
        <td align="left">
            <select name="selectMultiple" size="10" multiple="multiple" id="selectMultiple">
                <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
                <option value="Expenses">Expenses</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left"><input name="submitBtn" type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="javaScript:drawMultiChart();" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: you have a spelling error in the drawOneByOne function arg. I would suggest checking what the console in the browser says and fix those errors first.

Comment: I did check the spelling error. It still doesn't work. I'm using Dreamwaver to code, it doesn't show any error. But I run the code, the chart didn't appear.